# JList find out what item was clicked

Tags: java, swing, jlist

In order to get icons next to my items in the JList ive followed a tutorial to create a basic class to store my JList items. I then use this class as my listmodel to print out the icons and texts for each item.

Im also using a getListCellRendererComponent in order to print the text and icons.

My ListItem class looks like this:

```
public class ListItem 
{
    private ImageIcon icon = null;
    private String text;

    public ListItem(String iconpath, String text) 
    {
        icon = new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(iconpath));

        this.text = text;
    }       

    public ImageIcon getIcon() 
    {
        return icon;
    }

    public String getText() 
    {
        return text;
    }
}
```

MyCellRenderer:

```
public class MyCellRenderer
extends JPanel
implements ListCellRenderer
{
    private JLabel label = null;

    public MyCellRenderer()
    {
        super(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

           setOpaque(true);


        label = new JLabel();
        label.setOpaque(false);

        add(label);                
    }


    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, 
                                                  Object value, 
                                                  int index,    
                                                  boolean iss,  
                                                  boolean chf)  
    {


        label.setIcon(((ListItem)value).getIcon());

        label.setText(((ListItem)value).getText());

        if(iss) setBackground(Color.lightGray); 
        else setBackground(list.getBackground()); 

        return this;
    }
}
```

And finally, this is how i create my list:

```
listmodel = new DefaultListModel();

ListItem item0 = new ListItem("/resources/icnNew.png", "Element 1"),
         item1 = new ListItem("/resources/icnNew.png", "Element 2");

listmodel.addElement(item0);  
listmodel.addElement(item1);


list = new JList(listmodel);

list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);

list.setFixedCellHeight(32);        

list.setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());

menuScrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);

pnlVisitorsList.add(menuScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

How can i loop through the whole list and get the Element names?

For example
Element 1, 
Element 2

I want to look all the items and change the names and icons..

Comment: *"JList find out what item was clicked"* in the title is quite different to *"How can i loop through the whole list and get the Element names?"*  Which is it?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// LOOP

// loop through all elements in the list
for (int i=0; i<listmodel.size(); i++) {

    // get the listitem associated with the current element
    final Object object = listmodel.get(i);
    if (object instanceof ListItem) {
        ListItem listitem = (ListItem) object;

        // use getText() to get the text asociated with the listitem
        System.out.print(listitem.getText());

        // test if the current item is selected or not
        if (list.isSelectedIndex(i)) {
            System.out.print(" (selected)");
        }

        // next
        System.out.println();
    }
}

// CHANGE NAME + ICON

// create a new list item
ListItem itemNew = new ListItem("/resources/icnNew.png", "Element 3");

// replaced the first item in the list with the new one
listmodel.set(0, itemNew);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this you made me help understand how this works!!